# How do I stop threads from taking another threads job?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sorting, merge

I have taken a given int array and broken it into multiple sub arrays and put it into an ArrayList.

1) I need to spawn one thread per index of a. (this is not working and causing threads to used the same data)

2) I need to send each thread to be sorted via the quicksort class.(as it stands this works)

3) I also need to merge all the threads sorted arrays into one sorted array.(not sure how to do this either)

```
public void run(ArrayList<int[]> a) {
        Quicksort x = new Quicksort();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            store = a.get(i);
            System.out.println(store);
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    x.sort(store);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(store));

                }
            }.start();

        }
    }
public class Quicksort {
     private int array[];
    private int length;

    public void sort(int[] inputArr) {

        if (inputArr == null || inputArr.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.array = inputArr;
        length = inputArr.length;
        quickSort(0, length - 1);
    }

    private void quickSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = higherIndex;

        int pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];

        while (i <= j) {

            while (array[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            while (array[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                exchangeNumbers(i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        if (lowerIndex < j)
            quickSort(lowerIndex, j);
        if (i < higherIndex)
            quickSort(i, higherIndex);
    }

    private void exchangeNumbers(int i, int j) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

}
```

how I populate a

```
public class ArrayLists {

    private ArrayList<int[]> List = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayLists(int[] a, int size) {
    int[] temp = new int[size];
    int count = 0;
    while (count + size <= a.length) {
        temp = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, count, count + size);
        List.add(temp);
        count = count + size;
    }
    int[] temp2 = new int[a.length - count];
    if (count != a.length && count < a.length) {
        temp2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, count, a.length);
        List.add(temp2);
    }
    run(List);
}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: how do I stop this from using the same data in two different threads

Comment: The problem is not the threads, probably. How do you create the arrays? Post an MVCE

Comment: not sure what MVCE is but I showed how I populate a.

Comment: There is no declaration of List. Then you use the same array(temp) repeatedly while making only one new memory allocation. This is probably the mistake. If this works let me know, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

the issue was how I used the store variable. I needed a final int[] instead of a static int[] global variable.